# Check If Google Location & Search is enabled

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

It seems that from Android OS version 4.1 there is a new setting, wich allows google applications use the user location.

I am developping a app that use the google maps api v2, and I made it location aware by using the following line:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Now i want to check if the user has checked the location & google search at the settings screen.

There is no problem reading if the wifi and the gps is enabled, but i can not find the way to check of the google location & search is enabled until now i have just found the following piece of code:

```
try {
    int gEnable= settings.System.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),Settings.ACTION_SEARCH_SETTINGS);
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it always throws the exception.

Thank you very much for reading my post.

**EDIT**

I will try to explain it more clear....
In my app I Just want to check programmaticaly if the "Location and google search" (as i show in the picture below) is checked.

[image]

Thank u very much for reading my question.

Comment: What exception does it throw? Can you show us a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, though considering to do something like this might be also a way.

```
    boolean enabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // Check if GPS is enabled, if not send user to GPS settings
    if (!enabled) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

besides LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER you could also ask for

LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, which is "a special location provider for receiving locations without actually initiating a location fix" or
LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, which uses the network location. Google doesn't do anything else than using the last two options in my opinion...
I hope that helps...